# Windows 10 CU - Can't find “Turn System Icons On or Off”

Tags: windows-10-v1703

CU = "Creators Update."

When I go to the Notification & Actions Settings, I'm supposed to see the option near the top of the page to "Turn System Icons On or Off," as seen in the image below.

[image]
<sub>(source: [tekrevue.com](https://cdn1.tekrevue.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/windows-10-turn-system-icons-on-off.jpg))</sub>

However, that's missing for me, see this picture:

[image]

I really want to make my system tray icons display, not hide inside the arrow (drop-up box). How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.

In the top left, I can type in the search box "icon" and click "Select which icons appear on the taskbar."

Answer (score 0):

It is now under Settings > Personalization > Taskbar -- Halfway down under Notification area